# How to extract / Filter on array objects in JSON using RethinkDB

Tags: json, rethinkdb, reql

I have a simple JSON structure, for example

```
{'a' : 'value' , 'b': ['b1','b2','b3'] , c: 'value'} ,
{ 'a' : 'value' , 'b': ['b5','b6','b7'] , c: 'value'},
and so on . . .
```

I was wondering on how do I filter json data which only have b1 or b2 . 
It wasnt very clear in this documentation [1] . I tried running the following query but I am pretty sure, thats not the correct way of doing it.

```
r.db('mine').table('business')
  .filter([{'categories':'Clothing'}])
```

[1] http://rethinkdb.com/docs/nested-fields/ruby/

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want all rows with a value in the `b` property that has a value of `b1`, you can just use the [`contains`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/contains/) method.

You use the `contains` method (with the `filter method) in order to do that:

```
r.db('mine')
 .tables('business')
 .filter(function (row) { return row('b').contains('b1'); })
 .run(conn)
```

In Ruby, that looks something like this:

```
r.db('test')
 .table('hello')
 .filter{ |row| row['b'].contains('b1') }
 .run(conn)
```

In Python, that looks something like this:

```
r.db('test')
 .table('hello')
 .filter(lambda row: row['b'].contains('b1'))
 .run(conn)
```

2. If you want all rows with a value in the `b` property that has a value of `b1` AND a value of `b2`, you can just use the [`contains`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/contains/) method with the `and` method.

JavaScript

```
r.db('mine')
 .tables('business')
 .filter(function (row) { 
   return row('b').contains('b1').and(row('b').contains('b2')); 
 })
 .run(conn);
```

Python:

```
r.db('test')
  .table('hello')
  .filter(lambda row: 
     row['b'].contains('b1') & row['b'].contains('b2') 
   )
  .run(conn)
```

3. If you want all rows with a an array that only contains the values 'b1' or 'b2', then you can use Daniel's way and use the [`.setDifference`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/python/set_difference/) method with the [`isEmpty`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/python/is_empty/) method.

JavaScript

```
r.db('mine')
 .tables('business')
 .filter(function (row) { 
   return row('b').contains('b1').and(row('b').contains('b2')); 
 })
 .run(conn);
```

Python:

```
r.db('test')
  .table('hello')
  .filter(lambda row: 
     row['b'].contains('b1') & row['b'].contains('b2') 
   )
  .run(conn)
```

Comment: Note that if you want to have documents that have *only* 'b1' or 'b2' in the `b` field, you can use set_difference in combination with is_empty like this:
`...table('business').filter( |row| row['b'].set_difference(['b1', 'b2'].is_empty()))` Any document where b contains items other than b1 and b2 will be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks Daniel  .  @Jorge Silva, I would really appreciate , if you could add the python equivalent of the same as well. I was trying to execute rql like query in python, I guess the syntax and function calls are a bit different.

Comment: Done! Can you explain what you mean by the syntax and function calls being a bit different? Just curious